# Can't create Developer ID Application code signing identity in Xcode

Tags: xcode, certificate, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

I can't create a signing identity from Xcode for Developer ID Application.
Xcodeshows the Reset button and clicking that Reset button simply opens developer.apple.com

I have tried creating a new Developer ID Application certificate from the developer.apple.com website and installed it in Keychain Access but Xcode still shows the Reset button. I've tried removing all the previous Developer ID certificates and public and private keys from Keychain Access but the button still says Reset instead of Create.

[image]

I've tried installing Xcode on another Mac and when clicking the Create button for Developer ID Application I get a popup saying:

> Your account already has a valid Developer ID Application certificate
>   but it is not installed locally

and then Xcode crashes.

[image]

Therefore I ended up with multiple Developer ID Application certificates created in my account but I can't use any of them.

[image]

Is there any way to remove those Developer ID application certificates from my developer account and start fresh?

Hopefully this will make Xcode show the "Create" button instead of "Reset" on my Mac.

This is Xcode 7.1.1 on OSX 10.11.1

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. And never resolved the fact that the date on the new certificate ending in 2019 and the one that kept showing up, and I kept deleting had 2017. Finally, With Developer ID chosen I switched from my team name to "none." a dialogue came up asking me to ID myself. So I chose my team name in the dialogue. Then everything worked!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete them you can do that by clicking on whichever certificate you want to delete and then clicking revoke. At that point if you still have any certificates in your keychain access, delete those as well. From there create a new certificate try downloading it and opening it to add it to your keychain and then seeing if it works in Xcode.

Comment: This won't work. As stated here: You can’t revoke Developer ID or Pass Type ID certificates using Member Center. Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH31-SW26

Comment: @Bogdan Scroll down a little bit and you will see a section called "Revoking Certificates Using Member Center", where it says exactly what I said to do.

Comment: As I said before, please read this line: You can’t revoke Developer ID or Pass Type ID certificates using Member Center.  That's what I am trying to say. Those Certificates have a disabled Revoke button. Please check this image: http://imgur.com/c80oly5

Comment: @Bogdan Ah, I thought you were referring to distribution or development certificates. Have you tried downloading the certificate?

Answer (score 0):

**The Private Key for a Developer ID Certificate Is Missing**

Optionally, contact Apple at product-security@apple.com if you need to revoke Developer ID certificates. Alternatively, you can continue to develop and distribute apps by creating additional Developer ID certificates, as described in [Creating Additional Developer ID Certificates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH31-SW32).

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Troubleshooting/Troubleshooting.html